# Error installing specific python packages in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

i've been trying to import specfic python packages in jupyter, so far
!pip install 
has worked for both numpy and sklearn, however when doing the same for pandas and matplotlib it raises the following exception

```
> Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Complete
> output from command /snap/jupyter/6/bin/python -u -c 'import
> setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-jprnodmm/pillow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-lfpgysu2 --python-tag cp37:   ERROR:
> running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating
> build   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7   creating
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
> copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL 
> copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/_binary.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py ->
> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
> copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL   copying
> src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL  
> running egg_info   writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO   writing
> dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt   writing
> top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt   reading
> manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   reading manifest
> template 'MANIFEST.in'   warning: no files found matching '*.c'  
> warning: no files found matching '*.h'   warning: no files found
> matching '*.sh'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
> '.appveyor.yml'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
> '.clang-format'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
> '.coveragerc'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
> '.editorconfig'   warning: no previously-included files found matching
> '.readthedocs.yml'   warning: no previously-included files found
> matching 'codecov.yml'   warning: no previously-included files
> matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution   warning: no
> previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in
> distribution   warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so'
> found anywhere in distribution   no previously-included directories
> found matching '.ci'   writing manifest file
> 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'   running build_ext
>   
>      The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>      Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-jprnodmm/pillow/setup.py", line 996, in <module>
>       zip_safe=not (debug_build() or PLATFORM_MINGW),
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py",
> line 145, in setup
>       return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 192, in run
>       self.run_command('build')
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>       self.distribution.run_command(command)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
>       self.run_command(cmd_name)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>       self.distribution.run_command(command)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py",
> line 78, in run
>       _build_ext.run(self)
>     File "/snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line
> 340, in run
>       self.build_extensions()
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-jprnodmm/pillow/setup.py", line 804, in build_extensions
>       raise RequiredDependencyException(f)   __main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg
>      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>     File "/tmp/pip-install-jprnodmm/pillow/setup.py", line 1009, in <module>
>       raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)   __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
>      The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
>      Please see the install instructions at:
>      https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
>   
>      ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow   Running setup.py clean for pillow
```

any idea why these two specific packages aren't installing properly with pip? im on ubuntu linux.

Comment: If you plan to analyze data with Python, I suggest you install the Anaconda distribution of Python instead of `pip install`ing packages one by one to your default Python installation: <https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+The+headers+or+library+files+could+not+be+found+for+jpeg+a+required+dependency+when+compiling+Pillow+from+source

Answer (score 2):

Those packages have specific build dependencies that are not currently available on your system:

> The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,   a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

From the errors, it looks like you need to install at least the `libjpeg-dev` package:

```
# apt update
# apt install libjpeg-dev
```

You may discover additional dependencies you'll need to satisfy before the binary components of the package will compile successfully.